# SQLAlchemy Session Object

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm having a confusion about the session object in SQLAlchemy. Is it like the PHP session where a session is all the transactions of a users or is a session an entity which scopes the lifetime of a transaction.

For every transaction in SQLAlchemy, is the procedure as follows:
-create and open session
-perform transaction
-commit or rollback
-close session

So, my question is, for a client, do we create a single session object, or a session object is created whenever we have a transaction to perform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be hesitant to compare a SQLAlchemy session with a PHP session, since typically a PHP session refers to cookies, whereas SQLAlchemy has nothing to do with cookies or HTTP at all.

As explained by [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html):

> A Session is typically constructed at the beginning of a logical
>   operation where database access is potentially anticipated.
>
> The Session, whenever it is used to talk to the database, begins a
>   database transaction as soon as it starts communicating. Assuming the
>   autocommit flag is left at its recommended default of False, this
>   transaction remains in progress until the Session is rolled back,
>   committed, or closed. The Session will begin a new transaction if it
>   is used again, subsequent to the previous transaction ending; from
>   this it follows that the Session is capable of having a lifespan
>   across many transactions, though only one at a time. We refer to these
>   two concepts as transaction scope and session scope.
>
> The implication here is that the SQLAlchemy ORM is encouraging the
>   developer to establish these two scopes in his or her application,
>   including not only when the scopes begin and end, but also the expanse
>   of those scopes, for example should a single Session instance be local
>   to the execution flow within a function or method, should it be a
>   global object used by the entire application, or somewhere in between
>   these two.

As you can see, it is completely up to the developer of the application to determine how to use the session. In a simple desktop application, it might make sense to create a single global session object and just keep using that session object, committing as the user hits "save". In a web application, a "session per request handled" strategy is often used. Sometimes you use both strategies in the same application (a session-per-request for web requests, but a single session with slightly different properties for background tasks).

There is no "one size fits all" solution for when to use a session. The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html) does give hints as to how you might go about determining this.